# MySQL + php: new query for each row of a query?

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications

This is a subject that pops up all the time where I am. For a type of query that returns a list of rows, we often want to perform a further query that gathers more information about that specific row, this often includes queries that themselves return a list of rows. An example of this would be an orders system which returns a list of customers, and each customer 'row' may also show a list of their orders (perhaps in a pop-up dialog).

Is it generally "better" to:

1. Perform one single query, using `GROUP_CONCAT` where possible and split out the results programatically (there are limitations to the length of a returned concatenation)
2. Perform 'child queries' for each row while looping through the results of a 'parent query'
3. Perform one 'parent query' to return the customer list and one 'orders' query using the SQL `IN` keyword to match the customer_ID's returned from the previous query. Looping through the results of the customer query, we can see if the customer_ID exists in the orders query and show orders that match.
4. Perform the second query as and when. The reasoning being that we don't always want to see the child results for every parent result (using a web app, we could use AJAX to grab the child result)
5. Something else?

I have been leaning towards #2, as conceptually it seems like the cleanest solution, but I can't help but think that it is a resource hog. Doing our own benchmarks for a particular set of results, #3 comes out quickest. #4 seems like it should be the quickest as some applications don't need to show all results, however, the intention might be to have the result ready and waiting, rather than another roundtrip to retrieve that row's child data. I'm not entirely sure how the mechanics of `FETCH_ASSOC` etc. work, but any recommendations are very welcome!

Comment: Any reason `INNER JOIN` or its relatives (`LEFT` and `RIGHT` `JOIN`'s) can't be used here? That said, if you are going to show the orders of a customer in a different page or you don't mind an AJAX call, I would suggest #4.

Comment: I like #3 if you are going to use all of the results right away.  Otherwise, use #4.  Another twist on #3 would be to package both queries together in a stored procedure that returns two result sets.  It would only be one trip to the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think #3 is better.
I suggest getting all customers, then a list of all orders of this customers (customer_ID IN (...)) then dispatching order to the correct customer on php's side if needed.

This way, you get only two query with all the information, and the dispatching part may be avoided (depend of the logic to do after this query).

Remember that most overhead with querys comes from the query itself (transfering query, then getting back data)
Database are higly optimised for things like search and joins, so selecting data isn't the bottleneck (until you reach very high numbers) so it's another solution.

Additionnaly, if you're selecting with index using IN, the database'll not even have to search for the term, it'll just look at the index, then go directly to each row.

Depending on your application, #4 is better if the user is going to look at only one or two orders list for like 100 customers displayed.

Anyway, considering making a sql query in a loop is generaly a bad practise/bad design/bad logic.